# WiX/Msi textbox border covered up by background image if text is too long

Tags: textbox, wix, windows-installer, border, customdialog

I have an edit control on my custom dialog, that defaults to a session property `SERVICE_URL`.

```
<Control Id="serviceUrlTextBox" Type="Edit" X="135" Y="45" Height="17" Width="215" Property="SERVICE_URL" />
```

If the text fits the textbox, everything looks alright, if the text is too long however, the border goes missing. If the user adds/removes text (once the dialog is shown), that doesn't change the appearance, only the initial length has an effect.
Using `Multiline="yes"` does not help, the text is never wrapped and there is no border either.

[image]  [image]

How can I keep the border even if the text is too long? I'm using WiX Toolset v3.8.

---

EDIT: The background plays a role, as Buzka suggested (notice the background "crowding in" when the text is too long). Clearly a bug. Any ideas how I can get it to work short of removing the background?

[image] [image]

That's how I have created the different background:

```
<Binary Id="dialogBackground" SourceFile="Resources\WixUIDialogBackground.png"/>
<Control Id="background" Type="Bitmap" Text="dialogBackground" Width="370" Height="243" X="0" Y="53" TabSkip="no"  />
<Control Id="explanationLabel" X="135" Y="23" NoWrap="no" RightAligned="no" Transparent="yes" Type="Text" Width="215" Height="100" Text="Please provide the URL of the SettingsService. If you prefer, you may change it at a later stage in the Settings." />
<Control Id="serviceUrlTextBox" Type="Edit" X="135" Y="45" Height="17" Width="215" Property="SERVICE_URL" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using v3.8 too, don't have that problem in my installer. I can see you use custom background color, maybe thats reason?

@Edit

I mean maybe you should set custom border to textbox too? Or try with default backgroud color.

@Edit

After LOOOOONG searching... i found [something like this](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4344/):

> Unfortunately, that's how MSI draws it. There's no concept of a custom
>   control in MSI UI, so there's nothing WiX can do to fix it.

So i think my answer was good, no chances to change it, cause it's not supported.

Comment: How do you add a custom border to the textbox?

Comment: No idea... i was only using [WixEdit](http://wixedit.sourceforge.net/) for short while, but i don't remember any function like that :( but i understand it was bacground color foult? So it's right answer?

Comment: Yes, +1 for the good guess of the background. But it does not solve my problem so far, as I should be able to keep the custom background.

Comment: I kinda solved ur problem :) "remove background color" did it help? yup. ;) then you changed question. not my foult you want have background even if its unchangable (set border to textbox)~